# Wordpress Multisite with Addon Domains (not parked domain)

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

as we now with wordpress multisite we should add our domain names in "Parked Domain" area.  for some reason i want to add my domains in "Addon Domain" section and use it for wordpress multisite.

in normal way if we add domain name in "addon domain" section it will load that empty folder created.

anyone could help?

Comment: Hello! WP Admin doesn't have a parked domain area or an addon domain area, can you explain further? Perhaps add a screenshot? Is this a WordPress question or a hosting control panel question?

Comment: im using cPanel.    its the same on direct admin control panel too

Comment: Ah this isn't a CPanel stack, you should speak with your hosts support or refer to CPanel support/communities/docs. This site is for WordPress development, and WP has no concept of a parked or add on domain, in a multisite all sites are just sites, so I have no idea what an Add on site is in WP terms or how it's different to a normal site